# How to Implement "Row Encoder" given in "What you get is what you see" paper using Keras/ Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have recently started working with a task where I am trying to generate Equations from the images of equations.[Implementation is given here](https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup) but it is in `LUA` and I could not understand that. So I tried to do something with `tensorflow 2` as the model is exactly same to the [What You Get Is What You See:
A Visual Markup Decompiler](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04938v1.pdf). In order to get that, I have the model from the paper as:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
inp = base_model.input
out = base_model.layers[-1].output # use only the last layer. It'll provide us (8,8,2048)
cnn_part = tf.keras.Model(inp, out)

class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, features, hidden):
    hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)
    attention_hidden_layer = (tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis)))
    score = self.V(attention_hidden_layer)
    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)
    context_vector = attention_weights * features
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

    return context_vector, attention_weights
```

It is pretty decent up until this point. Now comes the part where `Show attend and tell` and this paper have difference. We can not use `Dense` Layer and pass the outputs to the `Embedding Layer` directly as they have specifically said that:

> In attention-based image captioning (Xu et
> al. 2015), the image feature grid can be directly fed into
> the decoder. For OCR, the visual features fed in to the decoder contain significant relative sequential order information. Therefore we experiment with an additional RNN encoder module that re-encodes each row of the grid

Also they have said later that:

> In this model, the new feature grid V˜ is created from
> V by running an RNN across each row of that input.
> Recursively for all rows h ∈ {1, . . . , H0} and columns
> w ∈ {1, . . . , W0}, the new features are defined as V˜ h,w =
> RNN(V˜ h,w−1, Vh,w). In order to capture the sequential
> order information in vertical direction, we use a trainable
> initial hidden state V˜ h,0 for each row, which we name positional embeddings.

This is what they want to say:

[image]

Please help me in implementing the model structure.

I got the vague idea that I have to do something like using community help:

```
rnn_input = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((batch_size*height, width, channels))(convnet_output) # given by VGG
rnn_output = tf.keras.layers.RNN(hidden_dim, return_sequences=True)(rnn_input)
```

but I'm not sure how to exactly use `Attention + Decoder` with it? Could someone please help.

I think you can use `Decoder Model` as:

```
class RNN_Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units, vocab_size):
    super(RNN_Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.units = units

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.units,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
    self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.units)

  def call(self, x, features, hidden):
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(features, hidden)
    x = self.embedding(x)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)
    output, state = self.lstm(x)
    x = self.fc1(output)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x, state, attention_weights

  def reset_state(self, batch_size):
    return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))

encoder = CNN_Encoder(embedding_dim)
decoder = RNN_Decoder(embedding_dim, units, vocab_size)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True,reduction='none')

def loss_function(real, pred):
  mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
  loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)
  mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
  loss_ *= mask
  return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)
```